# What does 'less' mean in this "less any liabilities" context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> In both cases, the per-share dollar amount of the fund is calculated by dividing the total value of all the securities in its portfolio, **less** any liabilities, by the number of fund shares outstanding.

Quoted from http://www.investopedia.com/terms/n/nav.asp

Comment: This is about meaning-in-context, and is completely on-topic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means "minus any liabilities," or "after subtracting any liabilities." In other words,

( total_securities − liabilities ) / outstanding_fund_shares

It functions as a preposition modifying "the total value of all the securities in its portfolio." See http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/less#Preposition

<sub>Credit to FumbleFingers for the more succinct phrasing.</sub>

Comment: More succinctly, ***less = minus*** (as a mathematical operand). The cited extract is really just an extended text representation of the formula **per-share amount = (total value − liabilities) / number of shares**.

Comment: It's my first guess but I can't find a related definition in the dictionary. It is a verb here?

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo Not a verb -- it functions as a preposition modifying "the total value of all the securities in its portfolio." http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/less#Preposition